# What is the difference b/w equivariant and covariant arrows in Coq?

Tags: coq

In [*A New Look at Generalized Rewriting in Type Theory*](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8417/d08a7cc5d874608cecd543f915b8464e68fd.pdf), the paper says "The equivariant arrow `==>` is currently an alias for the covariant arrow `++>`."

Does this mean that the implementation are the same in Coq? If so, is there an update about the definition of `==>`?

I have this question since I have not seen two words above *equivariant* and *covariant* in the same document...